# What's the use of textContent/innerText when innerHTML does the job better?

Tags: javascript

This might be a newbie question for most of you but it was explained to me that innerText ONLY gets the element's text and it can't be modified using any HTML tags, while innerHTML does the same job and HTML can as well be used. So, what's the point in having all of them?

Comment: There's no such thing as `innerContent`. Do you mean `textContent`?

Comment: sometimes you don't want an element to render html. XSS being one of them

Comment: Oops was typing fast, textContent yes!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Advantages of `textContent` over `innerHTML`:

- It works on all nodes, not only elements.

  ```js
  var node = document.createTextNode('hello');
  node.innerHTML; // undefined
  node.textContent; // 'hello'
  ```
- It gets the text contents of an element, without having to strip HTML tags manually.

  ```js
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.innerHTML = 'A<p>B<span>C</span>D</p>D';
  el.textContent; // "ABCDD" (HTML tags stripped successfully)
  ```
- It sets the contents of an element to a bunch of plain text, without having to HTML-escape it.

  ```js
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.textContent = 'A<p>B<span>C</span>D</p>D';
  el.children.length; // 0 (plain text HTML-escaped successfully)
  ```

Sure, when you use them on elements, `innerHTML` can be more powerful. But when you only care about the text content but not HTML content, `textContent` is simpler and likely to have better performance.

So we have both of them, and choose the most appropriate for each case.

Comment: I see, thanks for the detailed info! I got a better view of how important both are.

Comment: Internet Explorer does not support textContent, it uses innerText instead, which is a non-standard property only available in IE. It's an ugly incompatibility that forces us to use innerHTML if we don't want to always write multiple scripts.

Comment: @NoName Internet Explorer 9 supports `textContent`.

Comment: @Oriol That may be the case, but many companies still require its developers to provide support for older versions of IE which cannot understand textContent.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an element that's just supposed to contain text, without any HTML formatting, you can assign to `.textContent` and not have to worry about the string possibly containing characters that look like HTML. For instance, suppose you have an input field, and the user enters something into it, which you then put into a DIV. The user isn't supposed to be able to enter HTML in the input field, so you want to copy it literally. So you write:

```
div.textContent = input.value;
```

If you wanted to do this with `.innerHTML`, you would have to write something like:

```
div.textContent = input.value.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/&/g, '&amp;');
```

to prevent HTML from being interpreted.

When reading from an element, you can use `.textContent` if you just want to get the plain text of it, and ignore any formatting. E.g. if you have

```
<div id="x">This is <strong>important</strong> stuff</div>
```

you would use `document.getElementById("x").textContent` to get just `"This is important stuff"`, and not have to remove the `<strong>` tag yourself.

BTW, don't use `innerText`, it's nonstandard and not supported in FireFox.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I got what you meant! So I use either innerHTML or textContent and try to avoid innerText?

Comment: You escaped `&` as `&gt;`. I think you wanted to escape it as `&amp;`, and `>` as `&gt;`.

Comment: Thanks. No need to escape `>` when you've already escaped all the `<`.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, textContent does not work in IE 11. So far, innerHTML is pretty much the only one that consistently works on all browsers (I've tested my sites using it on 15+ versions of Firefox, several versions of IE (using virtualized Windows) and 20+ other browsers (including ones no one else has heard of). It works on every platform I've tried: Windows, Linux, OS X, Android, iOS.

I understand the potential security issues. This is why you ***always*** verify inputs into a form before posting them (and check them again if they are passed to another page for processing).